# ModelState.IsValid return false when the textbox was hide

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

User need to select the seller type to register the account.

If user select 'Private', the ROC input no need to enter the data. But if user select the 'Company', user need to enter the data in ROC

So what I do, If the user select the seller type as **'Company'**, I will hide the div called **rocDiv** in views with Jquery.

In server side, I also check for double confirmations.

The problem is, the ModelState.IsValid property keep return false if the user select seller type as "private".

Here the code snippet

Model **CreateNiagaModel**

```
 public class CreateNiagaModel
        {
            [DisplayName("Merchant Name : ")]
            [Required]
            [MaxLength(20)]
            public string merchant { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Merchant Description : ")]
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
            [MaxLength(250)]
            public string merchant_desc { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("Seller Type : ")]
            [Required]
            public string sellerType { get; set; }

            [DisplayName("ROC : ")]               
            public string roc{ get; set; }
}
```

Views

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "Private",

             Value = "private"
         });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "Company",
             Value = "company"
         });
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.merchant, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.merchant, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Your business name", @title = "Testing" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.merchant, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.merchant_desc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.merchant_desc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Explain about your business", @rows = 5 } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.merchant_desc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sellerType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sellerType, listItems, "--Select Type--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "sellType" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sellerType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="form-group" id="rocDiv">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.roc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.roc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.roc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#rocDiv').hide();
     $('#sellType').change(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value == 'company') {
         $('#rocDiv').show();
        } else {
         $('#rocDiv').hide();
        }
       });
</script>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(CreateNiagaModel CN)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //Do some logic
    }
    else
    {
      //Code always go here if user select 'private' in seller type
    }
}
```

How can I solved this problem? Or any other way can I do? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your property `roc` does not have a validation attribute and the issue has nothing to do with the fact that the textbox is hidden or not. Check the value of `ModelState` to determine which property has an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `IValidatableObject` interface.

```
public class CreateNiagaModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [DisplayName("Merchant Name : ")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string merchant { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Merchant Description : ")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string merchant_desc { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Seller Type : ")]
    [Required]
    public string sellerType { get; set;

    [DisplayName("ROC : ")]               
    public string roc{ get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext ctx)
    {
        if (sellerType == "company" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(roc))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("ROC is required when seller type is Company", new[] { "roc" });
        }
    }
}
```

This validation logic is performed by MVC when validating the viewmodel, and also by Entity Framework when saving changes if you use the same model there.

EDIT: I reread your question and I might have misinterpreted it the first time. It looks like `ModelState.IsValid` should be true when seller type is "private". I would set a breakpoint on the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` line and inspect the errors to see exactly what is causing the validation to fail.